# How to process files concurrently with bash?

Tags: bash, file, concurrency

Suppose I have 10K filesa and a `bash` script which processes a single file.  Now I would like to process all these files concurrently with only `K` script running in parallel. I do not want (obviously) to process any file more than once.

How would you suggest implement it in `bash` ?

Comment: if K is not too big, use different processes

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One way of executing a limited number of parallel jobs is with [GNU parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/). For example, with this command:

```
find . -type f -print0 | parallel -0 -P 3 ./myscript {1}
```

You will pass all files in the current directory (and its subdirectories) as parameters to `myscript`, one at a time. The `-0` option sets the delimiter to be the null character, and the `-P` option sets the number of jobs that are executed in parallel. The default number of parallel processes is equal to the number of cores in the system. There are other options for parallel processing in clusters etc, which are documented [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html).

Answer (score 5):

I bash you can easily run part of the script in a different process just by using '(' and ')'. If you add `&`, then the parent process will not wait for the child. So you in fact use `( command1; command2; command3; ... ) &`:

```
while ... do
    (
        your script goes here, executed in a separate process

    ) &
    CHILD_PID = $!
done
```

And also the `$!` gives you the PID of the child process. What else you need to know? When you reach the `k` processes launched, you need to wait for the others. This is done using `wait <PID>`:

```
wait $CHILD_PID
```

If you want to wait for all of them, just use `wait`.

This should be sufficient for you to implement the system.

Answer (score 1):

```
   for f1 in *;do
      (( cnt = cnt +1 ))
      if [ cnt -le $k ];then
         nohup ./script1 $f1 &
         continue
       fi
       wait
       cnt=0
   done
```

please test it . dont' have time to

Comment: The drawback to this is that once you've started `cnt` processes, you won't start another job until *all* of them have completed.