# Error in executing bash code

Tags: bash

I am trying to paste two cuts in bash, but it throwing an error `Syntax error: "(" unexpected` when i am trying to run in loop. however the same code is working on a single file. Can anyone please help me.

this is working

```
paste -d,  <(cut -d, -f -2 IE3BW0047A_03012017000949.csv) <(rev IE3BW0047A_03012017000949.csv | cut -d, -f -7 | rev)
```

but execution in loop is not working

```
for filename in *.csv; do
    paste  -d , < (cut -d, -f -2 "$filename") < (rev "$filename" | cut -d, -f -7 | rev) > ${tgt_wd}/"$filename"
done
```

Comment: https://www.shellcheck.net

Comment: As you indicated you were using `sh`, POSIX shell does not recognize process substitutions. Even your `/bin/sh` is  link to `bash`, it will parse `<(...)` as an incorrect input redirection, to maintain POSIX compatibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should be no space between `<` and `(` in process substitution:

```
for filename in *.csv; do
    paste  -d , <(cut -d, -f -2 "$filename") <(rev "$filename" | cut -d, -f -7 | rev) > ${tgt_wd}/"$filename"
done
```

Comment: Error still exists

Comment: Did you fix it in both places?

Comment: any more ideas?

Comment: @occasionalvisitor Are you actually executing the code with `bash`?

Comment: How can i achieve the same functionality using python ?

Comment: @occasionalvisitor: I don't know where you got the idea that I know python... I haven't touched the language.

Comment: Actually i am trying to implement the same in python. So just thought if anyone can put their ideas :)

Comment: @user000001 can you tell me as how can i make it execute using multiple threads to make the execution faster

Comment: To use multiple threads, I'd recommend GNU parallel. I answered a similar question about processing files concurrently here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17383453, if that helps. On the other hand, the fastest way would probably be to replace the whole thing with a single awk script, but I think we're getting off topic of the original question. If you have problems implementing any of these solutions, you could consider asking a new question.

Answer (score 1):

I made it into tmp files and it worked.

```
#!/bin/bash

for filename in *.csv; do
    cut -d, -f -2 "$filename" > 1_"$filename"
    rev "$filename" | cut -d, -f -7 | rev > 2_"$filename"
    paste  -d, 1_"$filename" 2_"$filename" > "$tgt_dir"/"$filename"
    rm 1_"$filename" 2_"$filename"
done
```